# UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'filename' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python

What is the best way to fix this? Please help.

Here is my Code.

```
           if command == '/enable':
             filename='line_en.xml'
            else:
             if command == '/disable':
              filename='line_dis.xml'
        
             with open(filename) as f:
              data = f.read().replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').encode()
             response = requests.put('http://www.xxxx.com')
```

```
with open(filename) as f:
              ^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'filename' where it is not associated with a value
```

Comment: If you command variable has a value different from enabled/disable you will get an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `match case` advantage over if-elif-else.

snippet:

```
command = '/enable'

match command:
    case '/enable':
        filename = 'line_en.xml'
    case '/disable':
        filename = 'line_dis.xml'

with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read().replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').encode()

response = requests.put('http://www.xxxx.com')
```

Comment: Glad I could improve coding.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is an indentation problem in your code.
Make sure the with `open(filename) as f:` line is aligned with the corresponding if and else blocks. This should resolve the UnboundLocalError issue.

```
import requests

command = '/enable'

if command == '/enable':
    filename = 'line_en.xml'
else:
    if command == '/disable':
        filename = 'line_dis.xml'

with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read().replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').encode()

response = requests.put('http://www.xxxx.com')
```